# How can I create a "gallery" with singularitygs?

Tags: css, sass, singularitygs

I'm trying to create a small gallery in the footer of my site. At the moment, the following Sass does actually work but it doesn't seem very efficient to use the *one*, *two* and *three* classes on each footer_block but I simply can't see another way of doing this.

Essentially I have a symmetrical grid nested inside an asymmetrical grid and would like to repeat the same grid-span call for each of the three footer_block items but have failed to figure out how.

The Sass looks like:

```
.region--footer {
  color: $color__background--dark;
  border: {
    top: 1px solid $base-ui-color;
  }
  font-family: $secondary-font-family;
  font-size: $font-size-sm;
  .content {
    padding: {
      bottom: em(32px, $font-size-sm);
      top: em(32px, $font-size-sm);
    }
    @extend .cf;
    @include add-grid(4 10 3);
    @include add-gutter(1/4);
    @include add-gutter-style('split');
  }
}

.footer__blocks {
  @extend .cf;
  @include grid-span(1, 2);
  @include layout(3, $gutter: 0) {
    .footer__block {
      @include grid-span(1, 1);
    }
    .footer__block.two {
      @include grid-span(1, 2);
    }
    .footer__block.three {
      @include grid-span(1, 3);
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<footer class="region--footer">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="footer__blocks">
      <div class="footer__block one">
        <img src="image.jpg">
    </div>
      <div class="footer__block two">
        <img src="image.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="footer__block three">
      <img src="image.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Float span

Here's a solution:

```
.footer__blocks {
  @include grid-span(1, 2);

  $cols: 3;

  @include layout($cols, $gutter: 0) {
    .footer__block {
      @include float-span(1);
      &:nth-child(#{$cols}n+#{$cols}) {
        @include float-span(1, 'last');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/5dab07e1ab0b861e4b4a

1. We use `float-span(1)` to span items in a symmetrical grid. It allows us to use the same definition for all items, rather than applying a unique position for every item.
2. The last item in each row should have no right gutter. The `&:nth-child(3n+3)` selector targets every third item in all rows. We apply a `float-span(1, 'last')`, telling Singularity not to add right margin.

### Singularity Quick Spanner

You can also make use of my [singularity-quick-spanner](https://github.com/lolmaus/singularity-quick-spanner) extension to simplify things even further. It lets you achieve the same result as above with a single line of code:

```
.footer__blocks {
  @include grid-span(1, 2);

  @include layout(3, $gutter: 0) {
    .footer__block {
      @include thumb-span(3); // Magic! :D
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/c2c4ab643165c9da2526