# Why don't my floats in my Singularity grid fill all the columns?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

Here is the SassMeister. It's a four column sub-layout with floated menu items and i'd like them to fill the columns, but instead they cluster in the first three because the margins are too big.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/b45986bb5bcbc464b3aa

Any insights into why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's some messy Drupal markup! You should've cleaned it up and post a reduced demo of your problem rather than just copy-pasting all the mess.

The `float-span` mixin sets a right margin for an item unless you specify the second argument to be either `'last'` or the number of the last column.

The reason why this fails is that you have 4 columns and 3 gutters in your grid, but you tell Singularity to produce per row 4 one-column items with a gutter each, and you end up with 4 columns and 4 gutters. The last item won't fit and is wrapped to the next row.

The solution is to apply `'last'` to every fourth item:

```
.menu-block-1  .leaf {
  @include float-span(1);
  &:nth-child(4n+4) {
    @include float-span(1, 'last');
  }
}
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/5723f9c604752802af05

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the mess haha. Next time I'll clean before I post.

Comment: Oh, and also check out Singularity Quick Spanner! http://stackoverflow.com/a/28761624/901944