# singularity css grids add one gutter to the width

Tags: css, singularitygs, gutter

Is it possible to add one gutter-width to the overall width to the grid ?

**Example:**

```
@include add-grid(2);
@include add-gutter(1/2);
@include sgs-change('output', 'float');
```

You have a floating 2 column layout with a 1/2 gutter. Singulartiy calculates with 100% width. If you not defining the last item, all the elements would be on the left. It is not clear what the last element is. So i have to expand the grid by one gutter (So all elements would show correctly) and then add the gutter width to the main container.

So I would need to build a grid like this:

```
@include add-grid(2 2 1);
@include add-gutter(1);
```

to have the same effect. Does anything exist to do this in a "nice" way ?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Can you make a demo no SassMeister.com?

Comment: i was actually looking for some showcase generator with sass and singularity, unfortunately i get an error when importing singularity in  sassMeister.com

Comment: Sounds like this problem I had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748099/why-dont-my-floats-in-my-singularity-grid-fill-all-the-columns, I realized for floats you need to have all the ones in the last column marked as last IE "@include float-span(1, 'last');"